# www domain on port 80 ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

domain.com:80 is working fine
But [www.domain.com:80](http://www.domain.com:80) is giving this error

> sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

SSL is from AWS ACM and load balancer listeners along with route 53

What i am missing here??

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have added only `domain.com` as your Fully qualified domain name.

You can add additional fully qualified domain name (FQDN), such as `www.domain.com`, or You can also use an asterisk (*) as a wild card in the leftmost position to protect several site names in the same domain (`*.domain.com`)

**And one more thing is default HTTPS(SSL) port is 443 not 80**

Comment: i already have wild card entry. whenever i type www.domain.com is redirecting me to www.domain.com:80 but domain.com is working fine.this only happens if i dont write https

Comment: @Manav Are you sure you are using https protocol?

Comment: yes with elb in route 53